# What do I need from Rackspace to deploy an alfresco instance?

Tags: alfresco, rackspace

I want to setup my test/dev environment for Alfresco on Rackspace cloud, since I'm already using their services.

Now, Alfresco needs 2 things: tomcat + some filesystem (1 gig max would be ok for start), and a mysql database.

Now, I've never been setting up anything like that, so I'm looking for recommendations. Is it feasible and what do I need, so I can run it only when testing (and ditch one of the boxes from under my desk)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly listed most of the things you require to get Alfresco up and running. The only recommendation I have for you is about physical memory: experience says that Alfresco needs at least 512m to run, plus ~256M of PermGen space. I'd say you need 1G RAM box.

Comment: Thanks. Also, rackers helped me, they said I should take a 4GB box so I can work with mysql on the same box too.